# Is XmlTextWriter the fastest way to write out an XML file?

Tags: .net, xml, xmltextwriter

At present I am using XmlTextWriter with WrieStartElement(), WriteAttributeString(), & WriteEndElement(). Is this the fastest way to create an XML file?

Update: I'm looking at XML writers, not raw string writers. Between characters that need to be escaped, handling namespaces, etc. I have no desire to re-invent the wheel. And I doubt I would be any faster after I take all that into account.

Comment: Suggestion: try a different way of doing it (make sure you do all the escaping of special characters correctly), and measure both.

Comment: No, writing strings manually is faster. Writing bytes (and not going through Encoding) is even faster

Answer (score -1, accepted):

And the answer is no ([details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/08/the-world-has-moved-on-have-you-xml-apis-you-should-avoid-using.aspx)). Use XmlWriter instead. The summation of the linked article is "because Microsoft said XmlWriter is replacing XmlTextWriter.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Summation added (although Use XmlWriter is an accurate summation).

Comment: @DavidThielen A summation isn't really the best - any chance you add additional details from the blog post (ie, **why** is Microsoft saying this?)?